# A question on independence

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so we have

$$f(x \mid y) = f(x)$$

Suppose there is another random variable $z$. Is it necessarily the case that

$$f(x\mid y, z) = f(x \mid z)$$

holds?

I'm struggling to come up with a counter-example, and I haven't been able to do so. On the other hand, I'm not able to prove it.

I read the questions on pairwise independence, but I'm not sure if the concept of pairwise independence helps.

Can I get a hint?

Comment: "Is it necessarily the case" for what?

Comment: Is it necessarily the case that $f(x \mid y,z) = f(x \mid z)$ holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X, Y$ be independent, and let $Z = X + Y$. Then the equality does not hold because given $Y$ and $Z$, $X$ is known exactly ($X = Z - Y$), but given just $Z$ and not $Y$, $X$ is not known.

The density $f(x \mid y, z)$ will be a [Dirac $\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) at $z - y$. The density of $f(x \mid z)$ will be $f_Y(z - x)$, where $f_Y$ is the pdf of $Y$.